# Can I run dart processes in the background while Flutter is closed? (Desktop)

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I'm currently developing an application for the Linux desktop.
It essentially checks an online server for file changes and updates a folder on the local filesystem accordingly. most of the processing is done in the background. However, there is a Flutter application that sets all the preferences, allows the user to explore the server filesystem etc.

Currently I use the app_window package to hide the window when not required and I use a system tray icon that allows bringing the window back into view. As far as I can tell, this keeps the Flutter app running in the background.

Is there a way to exit the Flutter app, whilst keeping other dart code running in the background. I would then relaunch the flutter app once the I receive an event from the system tray listener (using runApp).